# Path problem with circuitikz package

Tags: nodes, circuitikz

I want to reproduce these basic diagrams with `circuitikz` package.

[image: NORGATE] [image: NANDGATE]

However, I’m still struggling with the component’s path-style, anchors … The next MME gives more details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

%node[european and port]{}
%node[european or port]{}
%node[european nand port]{}
%node[european nor port]{}
%node[european xor port]{}
%node[european xnor port]{}
%node[european buffer port]{}
%node[european not port]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw (0,0) node[above]{$v_i$} to[short, o-] ++(1,0) node[european and port](AND1){};
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Also, where could I find these kind of information (coordinates, paths, references, …) that may help me drawing any circuit diagram with ease?

Comment: Have you tried the digital circuit tutorial in the `circuitikz` manual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
    logic ports=ieee,
    logic ports/scale=0.9,
    logic ports/thickness=3,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,1) node[ieeestd nand port](AND1){$G_1$}
    (0,-1) node[ieeestd nand port](AND2){$G_2$}
    (2.5,0) node[ieeestd nand port](AND3){$G_3$}
    (AND1.out) node[above]{$\bar{A}$} -- ++(0.5,0) |- (AND3.in 1)
    (AND2.out) node[below]{$\bar{B}$} -- ++(0.5,0) |- (AND3.in 2)
    (AND3.out) node[right]{$\overline{\bar{A}\bar{B}} = A + B$}
    (AND1.in 1) -- (AND1.in 2) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a)
    (a) to[short, *-] ++(-0.5,0) node[left]{$A$}
    (AND2.in 1) -- (AND2.in 2) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b)
    (b) to[short, *-] ++(-0.5,0) node[left]{$B$};
    
\draw (0,-3) node[ieeestd nand port](AND4){}
    (AND4.in 2) to[short, -*] (AND4.in 1) -- ++(-0.5,0) node[above]{$a$}
    (AND4.out) node[above]{$S_0$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]